# PySpark: Groupby within groups and display sum in separate fields based on certain values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, pyspark-pandas

I have a dataframe which contains Company name, EmpId, Bonus & Salary.

| COMPANY | EMPID | BONUS | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | 1234 | No | 5 |
| APPLE | 1235 | No | 7 |
| GOOGLE | 6786 | Yes | 6 |
| GOOGLE | 6787 | No | 5 |
| GOOGLE | 6788 | No | 6 |
| TARGET | 9091 | Yes | 4 |
| TARGET | 9092 | Yes | 1 |
| TARGET | 9093 | Yes | 9 |
| TARGET | 9094 | No | 2 |
| TARGET | 9094 | Yes | 4 |

I want to group by Company name regardless of EmpIds and create 2 different columns which will display total sum of Bonus & salary received by company.

Expected output:

| COMPANY | TOT_AMT_NO_BONUS | TOTAL_BONUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| APPLE | 12 | 0 |
| GOOGLE | 11 | 6 |
| TARGET | 2 | 18 |

Tried with groupBy, Aggregate & Sum but not getting results as expected. Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby company, pivot on bonus, and sum salary, then fill any null entries with 0:

```
sparkDF.groupby('COMPANY').pivot('BONUS').sum('salary').withColumnRenamed(
    'No', 'TOT_AMT_NO_BONUS',
).withColumnRenamed(
    'Yes', 'TOTAL_BONUS'
).fillna(
    value=0, subset=['TOT_AMT_NO_BONUS','TOTAL_BONUS']
)

+-------+----------------+-----------+
|COMPANY|TOT_AMT_NO_BONUS|TOTAL_BONUS|
+-------+----------------+-----------+
|  APPLE|              12|          0|
| TARGET|               2|         18|
| GOOGLE|              11|          6|
+-------+----------------+-----------+
```

Comment: This is awesome, Never used pivot before, this code snippet explains it very clearly. Thanks Derek.